Failed to uninstall Java on Mac OS : XPC connection error
I get this when trying to uninstall Java from the options in the Java panel in Mac System Settings:

Failed to uninstall Java XPC connection error

Java remains installed and I can't uninstall it. I have Java 8 installed.

The solution was to use this tool:
https://www.java.com/en/download/uninstalltool.jsp
Then exit out of System Settings and re-enter it and Java should be gone.

… and then use only SDKMAN! to locate, download, install, and uninstall JDK/JRE.
